# Shared object library not listing particular shared object dependencies

Tags: cmake

Using target_link_libraries in my CMakeLists.txt file results in only some of the shared-object library dependencies being set in the built library.

In my CMakeLists.txt file I have this:

```
set(STIREN_LIBS)
list(APPEND STIREN_LIBS
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.12
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
)
```

If I call target_link_libraries on that, as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${STIREN_LIBS})
```

I get this as the result of objdump -p

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libcairo.so.2
  NEEDED               libboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1
  NEEDED               libboost_regex.so.1.65.1
  NEEDED               libproj.so.12
  NEEDED               libxml2.so.2
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  NEEDED               ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
  SONAME               libstiren.so
```

**It is missing the dependencies for libicuuc and lifharfbuzz.** I confirm that those file paths are valid.

If I omit the target_link_libraries, I get this in the output of objdump -p

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  NEEDED               ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
  SONAME               libstiren.so
```

So why is it that only some dependencies making it through?

Comment: Probably, libraries `libicuuc` and `libharfbuzz` are simply **not needed** by your library, that is you use none symbols from these libraries.

Comment: I know that they are needed (libharfbuzz in particular).  But I will try adding a dependency to a different library which I know isn't needed, to see how that affects the objdump -p output.

Comment: Sorry, your comment was spot on and I totally misunderstood it. I know that I get loading errors when trying to run an application using the library, whereas when I use a different version (which has the right dependencies listed with objdump -p), I don't get those errors.  I know that libharfbuzz is needed but that must not be expressed correctly at some level in the code or the build script.  I'll investigate this further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, CMake does none magic about "physical" linking of libraries: it just passes libraries list as is to the linker. You may check the **actual** linker command line in `make VERBOSE=1` output.